# C++ on Mac: Permission Denied

Tags: c++

I created a dummy program to see if C++ was working, test.cpp:

```
int main(){
  int a = 10;
  return 0;
}
```

In my terminal, I typed:

```
gcc -Wall -c test.cpp -o test
./test
```

I got the following as the output:

```
bash: ./test: Permission denied
```

What can I do to be able to run my program?

Comment: Do you know what the `-c` flag does when you build your program? If you don't, then why do you use it? Have you tried *not* using it? Perhaps you should take some time to read [the documentation for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), or considering you're on a macOS system [the documentation for Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).

Comment: I can -c clearly now the switch is gone.

Comment: @JonDeaton I typed that into terminal and then ./test, but got an error saying "bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I got rid of the -c and I got an error: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: @ArjunGupta Can you try doing `chmod u+x test`? And then try and run it?

Comment: You are closer to success, though. I recommend adding the complete build output to your question. There will be a more descriptive error message in there somewhere.

Comment: @user4581301 What do you mean?

Comment: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` should be the tail end of the output. Earlier there should be a diagnostic explaining why the linker could not link the program.

Comment: @Annabelle I get an error saying "bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file".

Comment: @user4581301 The first line is "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:". Does that help?

Comment: Since it doesn't look like anyone has bothered looking it up, -c means stop building **before** linking an executable program. The job';s not done and you're trying to run [one of the intermediate steps of the building process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work).

Comment: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-1.6 This might be of interest.

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" means something is missing, but you've left out what it is that is missing. Edit the question and put all of the output in. Unless you know what line is important, it's a whole lot easier if you provide the whole thing.

Comment: @Annabelle Thank you! I did "g++ -o hello hello.cpp THEN chmod a+x hello THEN ./hello" and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're building a C++ program, you should use the `g++` program (or `clang++`). The difference between `gcc` and `g++` is that `g++` will link with the C++ standard library.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for all your help. As I wrote above, I believe I was simply using the wrong command. I used the commands in https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-1.6 and it worked just fine! Thanks once again!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a compiled language, therefore you cannot run it with "./test.cpp"

In my case it went as follows:

zsh:

1. % g++ test.cpp --> It generates an (a.out file)
2. % ./a.out --> It run flawlessly

;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nowhere in the question did the user mention attempting to run the app using `./test.cpp`.  They specifically named the file `test` using the `-o` option and attempted to run it.  By the way, the solution to this one is in the comments. ;-)